# Converting textfile to a two dimensional array (with a comma deliminator) VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying like crazy to figure out how to do this.  I need to look at a textfile that I've designed (for a quiz program)- line by line (the line having two parts separated by a comma) for the question (First part) and the boolean answer (second part).  Ie.   A line from the text file will look like:

```
You have 10 fingers,true
you have 10 toes,true
you have 2 thumbs,true
```

I just need to be able to convert this to an array whereby I can access the elements on command, so for instance (0,0) would display the first question in a textbox, and I would reference the users answer (in the form of true or false) against (0,1) where I would use a counter to count the number of correct answers.  After the user answers the first question I could loop to the second question to be displayed in the array and so forth.  Although there may be more advanced ways of doing this I will need to use a stream reader in this context.

I see I can read ONE line into an array with :

```
dim line() as string = io.file.readalllines("C:\data.txt")
dim value(2) as integer
value = line.split(","c)
```

but I need to access each line, with their answers, one at a time. If I could get the textfile into an two dimensional array I could simply access each element on command.  Help :)

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Just use `For Each` loop.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a proper class to handle your data. For example you could write a class named QA that stores the Question text and the boolean value of the answer

```
Public Class QA
    Public Question as String
    Public Answer as Boolean
End Class
```

You could read your file with File.ReadLines or use the StreamReader class.

```
Sub Main

    ' A list of QA objects loaded from file
    Dim qaList as New List(Of QA)()

    Using sw = new StreamReader("C:\data.txt")
        Dim line as String
        Do
            line = sw.ReadLine()
            If line Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            Dim  parts() = line.Split(","c)

            ' Initialize a new QA object and add it to the list
            qaList.Add(new QA() _
            With 
            { 
                 .Question = parts(0), 
                 .Answer = Convert.ToBoolean(parts(1)) 
            })
        Loop
    End Using
```

Now you could use the List(Of QA) as an array referencing the elements using an indexer

```
    Console.WriteLine(qaList(0).Question)
    Console.WriteLine(qaList(0).Answer)

End Sub
```